# jQuery: Get value from multiple fields and show in text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 6 different select boxes and a text field which I need to fetch the value from and combine in to one text field using jQuery.

I understand essentially I will build the value for the targetTextField with a string like this: `$('#targetTextField').val(opt1+opt2+opt3+opt4+opt5+opt6+textField);`

What do I use to fetch the value of `select#options1` and transform that in to `opt1`?

Would it be along the lines of `opt1 = $('select#options1').val();` or am I heading in completely the wrong direction?

I've created a basic jsfiddle with just two options at:

http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/2/

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#options").change(function(){
    var opt1 = $('select#options').val()
    }$('#targetTextField').val(opt1+opt2);
});
    $("#options2").change(function(){
    var opt2 = $('select#options2').val()
    }$('#targetTextField').val(opt1+opt2);
});
});​
```

HTML

```
<select id="options">
  <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="opt1Value1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt1Value2" >Option 2</option>
</select>
<select id="options2">
  <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="opt2Value1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2Value2" >Option 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="targetTextField" name="targetTextField" size="31" tabindex="0" maxlength="99">​
```

...but it doesn't appear to be working, so I've obviously misunderstood or missed something.

Comment: You've got your answer in your question :)

Comment: do you have one select box with six options or sex select boxes?

Comment: 6 separate select boxes and a text field

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you check my coding that i've added as you say I have the answer but something isn't linking up correctly.

Comment: Let's say user selection option 1 and option 2 from these two options. So, do you want the answer as "12" ?

Comment: Yes, using my example I want to display `opt1Value1opt1Value2` in the `targetTextField`

Comment: @VincePettit, your code is correct, but only repeating. find my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/rSVwJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this demo for you, hope it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/5/

```
$(function() {
$("#options").change(function(){
        setTarget() ; // Something has changed so lets rebuild the target
});
    $("#options2").change(function(){
        setTarget();// Something has changed so lets rebuild the target
});
});

// Just get the values you want and update the target
function setTarget(){
    var tmp = $("#options").val();
    tmp += $("#options2").val();
    $('#targetTextField').val(tmp);
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. If I was to add #options3 would I then add `tmp += $("#options3").val();` after the `tmp += $("#options2").val();`? Also what would I add to fetch the value of a text field (say with the ID #options3?

Comment: Yes, its correct, just add another *tmp += $("#options2").val();*. It will work for textfield also. Just use the val function ;-)

Comment: I updated the demo. However the change method on a textfield is trigged AFTER it lost focus.

Answer (score 0):

for dropdown try following

```
 $('select option:selected').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/EJXx7/) it should hopefully give you a pointer in what you need to do.
you can change the name to be a class and then just provide your format you want to display in the input. but from your question in presume it should be about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different id for select box

```
  var toalopt=$('select option1:selected').text();
    toalopt+=$('select option2:selected').text();
    toalopt+=$('select option3:selected').text();
    toalopt+=$('select option4:selected').text();
    toalopt+=$('select option5:selected').text();
    toalopt+=$('select option6:selected').text();

    document.getElementById('id where you want to club data').innerHTML=toalopt;
```

If you have same id

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#optionvalue).click(function(){
        var values ='';
        $('select[name="sameid"]').each(function(index,item){
            values +=$(item).val() +' ';
        });
            $('id where you want to club data').val(values);
    });

});
```

HTml will be normal select tag with id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add a class to each of your `select` elements to better identify them as a group:

```
<select id="options" class="auto-updater">
  <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="opt1Value1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt1Value2" >Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="options2" class="auto-updater">
  <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="opt2Value1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2Value2" >Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="targetTextField" name="targetTextField" size="31" tabindex="0" maxlength="99">
```

Then in jQuery, you can use `map()` to create an array of the values and display them:

```
$(".auto-updater").change(function() {
    var values = $(".auto-updater").map(function() {
        return ($(this).val() == "") ? null : $(this).val(); // ignore default option select
        // return $(this).val(); // include all values
    }).get();

    $("#targetTextField").val(values.join(','));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/4/)

You can see that I've set this up to ignore `select` elements which are left on their default value. If you uncomment the line beneath it will include all selects, regardless of value chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal code required for you as below:

```
$(function() {
       $("select").change(function(){
          var opts=$('option:selected').val();
          var oldVal=$('#targetTextField').val();
             $('#targetTextField').val(oldVal+opts);  
    });   
});​
```

Find the jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/rSVwJ/).