# Pass multiple fields and shown on a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

With refer to answer of [SOF's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904274/jquery-get-value-from-multiple-fields-and-show-in-text-field), I would like to get a fix to have selected option value pass to target field automatically after page load (on user's profile page).

I would also interested to know the change method on a textfield is trigged BEFORE it lost focus.

[Sample on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/46/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#options").change(function () {
        setTarget(); // Something has changed so lets rebuild the target
    });
    $("#options2").change(function () {
        setTarget(); // Something has changed so lets rebuild the target
    });
});

// Just get the values you want and update the target
function setTarget() {
    var tmp = $("#options").val();
    tmp += $("#options2").val();
    $('#targetTextField').val(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Where is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: do you mean `$(document).ready(setTarget)`? And you can use the `blur` event, right?

Comment: To answer the only question I can surmise: `$("#options3").keyup();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To have the selected option value passed at page load, had this event in your `$` function :

   ```
   $(function () {
       ...

       // Add it here
       setTarget();
   });
   ```
2. For the change on the textfield which is transmitted to the value, use `keyup` event instead of `change` :

   ```
   $(function () {
       ...

       $("#options3").keyup(function () {
           setTarget(); // Text has changed
       });

       ...
   });
   ```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/e2ScF/49/